# DELETE blocking INSERT

Tags: c++, sql, multithreading, deadlock, informix

**OS** : Solaris
**Database** : Informix

I have a process which has 2 threads:

Thread 1 dealing with new transactions and doing DB INSERTS
Thread 2 dealing with existing transactions and doing DB DELETES

**PROBLEM**

Thread 1 is continuously doing INSERTS(adding new transactions) on a table.
Thread 2 is continuously doing DELETES(removing expired transactions) from the same table based on primary key

INSERTS are failing because of Informix error `244` which are occurring due to page/table locking.

I guess, the DELETE is doing a Table lock instead of Row lock and preventing the INSERTs to work.

Is there any way I can prevent this deadlocking?

---

**EDIT**

I found another clue.  The `244` error is caused by a `SELECT` query.
Both `insert` and `delete` operation does a `select` from a frequently updating table, before doing the operation.

Isolation is set as `COMMITTED READ`. When I manually do a `select` on this table from dbaccess, when the deletes are happening, I get the same error.

Comment: Which version of Informix?  Do you have page locking or row locking on the table?  What is the form of the DELETE statement?

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if a DELETE was doing a full table lock when removing single elements by primary key. Rather, it is likely the longevity of one (or both) of the transactions themselves is eventually tripping a table lock due to the number of modified rows. In general, you can avoid deadlocks in volatile tables such as this by eliminating all but single-row operations in each transaction, and ensuring your transaction model is read-committed. At least thus has been my experience.

Comment: I got the clue of Full table lock, when I saw `IX` locks created by my process in `onstat` output. I feel `DELETE` would be the culprit. Please note that, a lot of successive single row deletes happen in that thread.

Comment: And they're all in the same transaction? If so, thats your escalator right there. Especially if they are on potentially random pages sprinkled all over hither and yon. Is it absolutely mandatory they be group-xacted ?

Comment: Each single row delete is in a transaction.

Comment: Cached (i.e. same) connection on the thread (I assume so for performance if nothing else) ?

Comment: @cppcoder: How is the single row delete written?  Is there an index on the relevant column(s)?

Comment: Could you please provide the SQL script you're using for deleting the expired rows?.. Are you doing this through ASIO library funcs?

Comment: @cppcoder he mentioned its on the primary key only, so I'm certainly hoping so.

Comment: Delete is done on the primary key. `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?`
It uses eSQL to execute the query. Also, Cascade delete is enabled.